# Java - How to remove special char in string array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an array of strings (phone numbers) and i need to remove `+`, which is in front of one of the elements (numbers) since it throws an `NumberFormatException` when i try to cast it to int.

The elements in array are `0888888888` `0888123456` `+359886001122` and i have already used `.split(" ")` in order to separate them. I've also tried `.split(" +")` in order to remove `+` from the last one, but this didn't work.

Comment: `split(" +")` won't work because `+` is a special regex character that needs to be escaped: `split(" \\+")`

Answer (score 9):

You have to use `replaceAll` instead of `split`, for example :

```
"0888888888 0888123456 +359886001122".replaceAll("\\+", "");
```

this will show you :

```
0888888888 0888123456 359886001122
//-------------------^------------
```

Then if you want to split each number you can use `split(" ")` like this :

```
String numbers[] = "0888888888 0888123456 +359886001122".replaceAll("\\+", "").split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

this will give you :

```
[0888888888, 0888123456, 359886001122]
```

**EDIT**

Or like @shmosel said in comment you ca use `replace("+", "")`

Comment: Or just `replace("+", "")`

Comment: @shmosel without slash it throw an error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0`

Comment: [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) doesn't use regex.

Comment: aaahhh, ok i get it @shmosel you are using `replace`, i use `replaceAll` for that i get this error, yes you are correct this can be done with `replace("+", "")`

Comment: Small addition: I always use Pattern.quote() when I use replaceAll . It makes it clear that I intend not to use regexes to other developers and it's a failproof way of making sure that you're not inserting accidental regexes.
In this case: replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"),"");

Comment: thank you @PieterDeBie for the information i appreciate it really :)

Comment: No problem, I've been bitten a few times by this so I like to share this solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with

```
var lv_numbers = "0888888888 0888123456 +359886001122".replace('+','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Split uses a regular expression, so you can define to include and optional '+' in the split matcher.

```
String [] result = "0888888888 0888123456 +359886001122".split("\\s[\\+]{0,1}");
```